# What is the SQL Select Statement for merging 2 sets of results with the same column names?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables named **table1** and **table2**.

**table1**

```
rid | name
 1  | John
 2  | Peter
 3  | Pettigrew
```

**table2**

```
rid | name
 3  | Mark
 4  | James
```

I just want to have a resultset which looks like

***RESULT:***

```
rid | name
 1  | John
 2  | Peter
 3  | Pettigrew
 3  | Mark
 4  | James
```

What is the select statement for this?

Comment: `SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem by adding the code that you've tried.

Comment: `UNION`, or `UNION ALL`. The latter is cheaper as the first requires a sort to remove duplicates - [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

Comment: Try to google http://goo.gl/VZlFIv

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your data, not the query - It returns 4 [when I have tested your query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9ca4e/2)

Comment: @GarethD, You're right.

Comment: I edited the question to put emphasis on disregarding duplicates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * from table1
union
select * from table2
```

UPDATE : Gary_W pointed out UNION replaces duplicate.

If you want to keep the duplicate use `UNION ALL`

Comment: FYI - "UNION" removes duplicates.  Use "UNION ALL" to keep duplicates and thus truly combine the tables.  Depends on your requirements.

Comment: `UNION ALL` did it right for combining all the results disregarding the duplicates